# Using R to compare sub-elements within a string ... and summarize it so that there are no duplicate sub-elements

Tags: r

I have a string like this:

```
data <- c("A:B:C", "A:B", "E:F:G", "H:I:J", "B:C:D")
```

I want to convert this to a string of:

```
c("A:B:C:D", "E:F:G", "H:I:J")
```

The idea is that each element inside the string is another string of sub-elements (e.g. A, B, C) that have been pasted together (with sep=":"). Each element within the string is compared with all other elements to look for common sub-elements, and elements with common sub-elements are combined.

I don't care about the order of the string (or order of the sub-elements) FWIW.

Thanks for any help offered!

--

Answers so far...

I liked d.b's suggestion - not the least because it stayed in base R. However, with a more complicated larger set, it wasn't working perfectly until everything was run again. With an even more complicated dataset, re-running everything more than twice might be needed.

I had more difficulty with thelatemail's suggestion. I had to upgrade R to use lengths, and I then had to figure out how to get to the end point because the answer was incomplete. In any case, this was how I got to the end (I suspect there is a better way). This worked with a larger set without a hitch.

```
library(igraph)
spl <- strsplit(data,":")
combspl <- data.frame(
  grp = rep(seq_along(spl),lengths(spl)),
  val = unlist(spl)
)
cl <- clusters(graph.data.frame(combspl))$membership[-(1:length(spl))]

dat <- data.frame(cl)  # after getting nowhere working with the list as formatted
dat[,2] <- row.names(dat)
a <- character(0)
for (i in 1:max(cl)) {
  a[i] <- paste(paste0(dat[(dat[,1] == i),][,2]), collapse=":")
}

a
#[1] "A:B:C:D" "E:F:G"   "H:I:J"
```

I'm going to leave this for now as is.

Comment: You could simplify the code to get your exact result quite a bit: `sapply(split(names(cl),cl), paste, collapse=";")` for instance.

Comment: `@thelatemail`. Sure, that seems to work also. Do you mind adding this additional sorting bit I ended up using into your suggestion? -- in the loop part, I used `a[i] <- paste(paste0(sort(dat[(dat[,1] == i,][,2], collapse=":")` Also, for whatever it's worth, the whole thing is a part of a big loop (n=1005) and is followed by `a <- sort(a)` 
  `for (l in 1:length(a)) {`
    `outframe[i,l] <- paste(a[l], ":", sep="")`
  `}`

Answer (score 3):

A possible application for the `igraph` library, if you think of your values as an edgelist of paired groups:

```
library(igraph)
spl <- strsplit(data,":")
combspl <- data.frame(
  grp = rep(seq_along(spl),lengths(spl)),
  val = unlist(spl)
)
cl <- clusters(graph.data.frame(combspl))$membership[-(1:length(spl))]
#A B C E F G H I J D 
#1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1

split(names(cl),cl)
#$`1`
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "E" "F" "G"
#
#$`3`
#[1] "H" "I" "J"
```

Or as collapsed text:

```
sapply(split(names(cl),cl), paste, collapse=";")
#        1         2         3 
#"A;B;C;D"   "E;F;G"   "H;I;J"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = character(0)
for (i in 1:length(data)){
    a[i] =  paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(data[sapply(1:length(data), function(j)
        any(unlist(strsplit(data[i],":")) %in% unlist(strsplit(data[j],":"))))],":"))), collapse = ":")
}
unique(a)
#[1] "A:B:C:D" "E:F:G"   "H:I:J"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It seems to work for the most part. However, I must note that when I tried using this script in a large scale, it failed to compress everything properly in ~1% of the cases (9 out of 1005) - compression was incomplete. By repeating the script, the remaining ~1% was resolved as well. I am not sure what caused the hiccup.